# How to implement database views in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle

I'm just wondering how to implement database views in Ruby on Rails. Can you guys put some working example? And thank you for every advises and examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean client-side views on the database or views within the database?

Most relational databases support views which encapsulate a projection or other set-based operation into a virtual table:

```
CREATE VIEW viewname AS
SELECT *
       ,some_derived_column
FROM basetable
WHERE some_filter_criteria
```

Rails typically uses a pattern called Active Record to map database tables/views into Ruby for access at that layer.  How you deal with it at that point is kind of wide open.